# Changing TextBox colour in a method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got an MVVM C# project that has a button on a form that does some processing.
It takes a few seconds to do the processing and thats fine. There is an associated textbox that I want to change the background colour of during the processing. I've been trying to do this with no success.

I have the background colour for the textbox bound to a property that I change at the beginning of the method called by the button (via a command binding). The method does the work, and then sets the background colour back to its default colour. No change occurs on the screen when the button is clicked.

I've tried putting the color change code inside a Dispatcher to get it to happen on the GUI thread, but this still doesn't work.

I'm now confused. How do I get the colour to change properly?

```
    private void SwitchRuns()
    {
        try
        {

            // Bound property (set up with Notification correctly)
            //
            CurRunTextBoxColor = Colors.Red;

            UIServices.SetBusyState(true); // sets cursor to wait

            ...
            Processing code
            ...

            CurRunTextBoxColor = Colors.LightGreen;

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            log.Error("Exception in SwitchRuns" + exp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the binding look like for the Background of your TextBox?

Comment: Are you blocking the Gui-Thread while you do your codeprocessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe is happening is your **SwitchRuns** method is called directly from the UI thread and therefore the UI thread is busy. Pushing the operation into a background thread should solve the issue:

```
private void SwitchRuns()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.SwitchRuns());
}

private void SwitchRunsAsync()
{
    // Bound property (set up with Notification correctly)
    //
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        CurRunTextBoxColor = Brushes.Red;
    }), DispatcherPriority.Send);

    // Place your load logic here in place of the sleep.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        CurRunTextBoxColor = Brushes.LightGreen;
    }), DispatcherPriority.Send);
}
```

Please note that I have also changed your **CurRunTextBoxColor** property to be a `Brush` and not a `Color` in order to get the binding to the `Background` property of a `TextBox` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CurRunTextBoxColor = Colors.Red;`

write : `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { myTextBox.Background = Brushes.Red });`

Comment: The OP did state that this is an MVVM application.